# How do I edit the text in this function.php file?

Tags: php

How do I change the text "This comment was edited." in this function.php?

```
<?php if ($edit_comment == "edited") {?>


<em class="comment-edited">


<?php if (isset($its_question) && $its_question == "question") {


esc_html_e('This answer was edited.','wpqa');


}else {


esc_html_e('This comment was edited.','wpqa');


}?>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? There's no code in your question, and no copy of `functions.php`. What are you using for comments? And where do you see "This comment was edited`?

Comment: The code disappeared initially. I've added it back.

Comment: Do you want to translate it?

Comment: @MikeNGarrett, No. I want to change it to [Comment Edited] but the change is not working.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) codex page helps you on your way? And the filter [`comment_form_defaults`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_defaults/)  could become handy also *(using it together with a function?!)*